# What the purpose of the function passed to linking function as a second parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've just stumbled upon the following piece of code:

```
var tooltipLinker = $compile(template);
tooltip = tooltipLinker(tooltipLinkedScope, function(tooltip) {
    if (appendToBody) {
        $document.find('body').append(tooltip);
    } else {
        element.after(tooltip);
    }
});
```

My question is what is the purpose of the function passed as a second parameter to the linking function **in the angular framework**? I'm **not** asking what's the purpose of the callbacks.

In the docs it says that `$compile` returns:

```
function(scope, cloneAttachFn=, options=)
```

So this second parameter function seems to be the `cloneAttachFn`. Now I'm wondering if it has the same purpose as the `cloneAttachFn` in `transcluded` function?

Comment: Could you do `console.log(tooltipLinker)` and show the output? Then we could explain what it's doing from reading it.

Comment: @4castle, `tooltipLinker` is a linking function as explained in [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Answer (score 1):

This function allows you to access the bound view and **clone** the template. It also allows you to place the previously cloned element wherever you want.

The difference with the traditional

```
var tooltipLinker = $compile(template);
var tooltip = tooltipLinker(tooltipLinkedScope);
```

tooltip is a reference to the original element, not a clone

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('clone', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function($scope, $element) {
        $scope.value = 10;
        var elem = angular.element('<div>{{value}}</div>');
        var compiled = $compile(elem)($scope);
        console.log('elem === compiled', elem === compiled);
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <clone></clone>
</div>
```

In the other hand when you provide a clone attach function the element will **always** be a clone of the original element.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('clone', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function($scope, $element) {
        $scope.value = 10;
        var e;
        var elem = angular.element('<div>{{value}}</div>');
        var compiled = $compile(elem)($scope, function(cloned, scope) {
          e = cloned;
        });
        console.log('elem === compiled', elem === compiled);
        console.log('elem === callback element', elem === e);
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <clone></clone>
</div>
```

In the first case the original element is compiled and ready to be placed in the DOM, in the second case the original element is compiled but the result is available in the clone.

If you `console.log` the element in the second case you will see that still has the interpolation symbols on it. You must place the clone in the DOM instead.

The purpose of the function is to tell angular what to do with the template reference, either link it directly or make a clone first and link the clone instead.

Comment: _you will see that still has the interpolation symbols on it_ - yes, so when is this going to be linked?

Comment: @Maximus Short answer it won't. This is why they give you a clone. You can still bind this element with a different scope or make some modifications and recompile it again. The first case modifies the *blueprint* for good, the second preserves the *blueprint* so you can still use it at a later time.

Comment: I don't really understand... if I just insert it into the DOM and it will have interpolation symbols on it - what's the purpose of it? I want it linked (bound) to some scope.

Comment: @Maximus In the first case you can insert both the original and the compiled element in the DOM because they are one and the same. In the second case you can only attach the clone, not the original element. Please note that I'm **creating an element before calling `$compile`** instead of using `$compile('<div></div>')`. You need not to worry about this because the result of calling the linking function(`var result = $compile(template)(...)`) is always the reference you want to use.

Comment: just to be on the same page: `var plainElem = angular.element('<div>{{value}}</div>');` - this is plain DOM element, `var lnFn = $compile(elem)` - linking function, `var linkedElem = $compile(elem)($scope)` - linked element, `$compile(elem)($scope, function(cloned, scope) {          e = cloned;        });` - `cloned` is plain DOM element. Are these correct?

Comment: Not right. `cloned` is not a plain DOM element but a linked one, cloned from `elem`. The purpose of the function is to tell angular what to do with the `elem` reference, either link it directly or make a clone first and link the clone instead. Why is this useful? Depends of what you want to do with `elem`, usually you don't need to clone elements because you only link once. Also remember that `var ref = $compile(elem)($scope, function(cloned, scope) { })` here `ref === cloned` instead of the usual `ref === elem`.